# How to upgrade to Pip 10?

Tags: python, pip

My Python has Pip 9.1 installed. Unfortunately, a package called Scapely has a bug and won't install. There's supposed to be a fix for Pip 10.0, but when I try to upgrade pip using "python -m pip install -U pip", but Python says "requirement already up-to-date" following this command.

Any way to install Pip 10.0 manually? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update :**

Since the new version is available you can just do

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

For a fresh install of **pip 10**:

**MAC OS and LINUX**

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sh
```

**WINDOWS**

Open [this](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) in browser and download using `Ctrl+S`.

Open this file using file manager.

**Or** in windows power shell or command line:

```
python get-pip.py
```

**Previous Answer:**

Download [this](https://codeload.github.com/pypa/pip/zip/master) master branch from github, or you can also clone the [repository](https://github.com/pypa/pip).

Once inside the folder, either cloned or unziped the downloaded file:

```
python setup.py install
```

Then to verify:
    pip -V
or

```
pip --version
```

Comment: Grazie mille! (Thank you very much :) )

Comment: `pip install --upgrade pip` to pip 10 wreacks havoc upon Ubuntu. https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1141

Comment: @ÍhorMé `main` import from `pip` is not supported in pip 10.

Answer (score 3):

A [Beta release of pip version 10](https://blog.python.org/2018/03/beta-release-of-pip-version-10.html) is on PyPI: you can just

`pip install --upgrade --pre pip`

Answer (score 1):

Until `pip==10.0.0` is released, you can let `pip` upgrade itself to the latest development version from its git repository:

```
$ pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/pypa/pip
```

This way you don't have to download `pip`s sources yourself, although [harshil9968](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3405554/harshil9968)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48953529/2650249) is also correct.

Once the new version is released, just do the usual

```
$ pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 1):

`upgrade` option is like below command.

```
pip install --upgrade 'pip==10'
```

Comment: I did `sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip==10.0.1` and it worked in my environment.

Answer (score -2):

try one of theese (or both) depending on which version of python / pip you use

```
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip
sudo -H pip2 install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: "'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." (Windows 10)

Comment: well then just ommit sudo -H :P and also start using proper OS :D btw pip 10 might not be out yet only development version according to my quick google search

Comment: Actually command you are using in your question should work on windows but as I said official release is 9.0.1 for now and 10.0.0.dev0 version is in testing for developers. You might try to install that from their github.